"とくてい" (or どくてい) meaning "doxxing"? (modern internet lingo)
In Yoru no Kurage wa Oyogenai, everyone is (in my eyes @.@) a bunch of zoomers/gen alpha with brainrot that are trying to become influencers, and use a bunch of unfamiliar new internet slang >.<. (In my day, インフルエンザ was a disease, and now インフルエンサー is the dream job of all kids xP).
Anyways, my boomer ranting aside, A-chan is chasing B-chan (because B-chan liked A-chan's art and stood up to an influencer over it, without knowing who A-chan was). B-chan catches A-chan chasing her, and accosts her, asking if she's a stalker, or trying to "doxx her".
Clip of the scene
To me, it sounds like the word B-chan uses for "doxx" is "てくてい" (or "どくてい"), but I can't find any link between that and doxxing when I look it up. What word is being used here to mean doxxing? And is it some new zoomer-lingo (which is why it's hard for me to find it)?

The word is 特定厨【とくていちゅう】. 特定 means "identification", and 厨 is this. It's someone who tries to identify or expose personal information about someone, such as addresses and real names, without consent.
